# Laravel Project after Cloning getting this error

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.8

> Warning: require(C:\Users\Uvindu Mohotti\Desktop\Sample
>   GIt\blog/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in C:\Users\Uvindu Mohotti\Desktop\Sample GIt\blog\artisan
>   on line 18
>       PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'C:\Users\Uvindu Mohotti\Desktop\Sample GIt\blog/vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\Users\Uvindu
>   Mohotti\Desktop\Sample GIt\blog\artisan on line 18
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\Users\Uvindu
>   Mohotti\Desktop\Sample GIt\blog/vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\Users\Uvindu
>   Mohotti\Desktop\Sample GIt\blog\artisan on line 18

This error is given in from after `php artisan serve` but I can't find why ?

Comment: Run `composer install` and `composer dumpautoload`. You may need to remove `composer.lock` first.

Comment: You need to run `composer update`  then `php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 1):

Give Permission to the relevant files.

Reference: [How to set up File Permissions for Laravel 5 (and others)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30639174)